# Visual Studio C++ 2015 project cannot be linked against glew64 static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, static-linking, glew, freeglut

In my Visual Studio C++ project, I have two configurations, for 32 bit and 64 bit.
I try to statically link against freeglut and glew libraries.
In 32 bit configuration, I set the library search path to a folder containing freeglut.lib and glew32.lib and In 64 bit configuration, a folder containing freeglut.lib and glew64.lib. (Under Properties => Linker => General => Additional Library Directories)

I set the Input library names as required (glew32.lib; freeglut.lib; % (AdditionalDependencies) & glew64.lib; freeglut.lib; % (AdditionalDependencies)

I can build for 32 bit without any problem. But for 64 bit, I get the error:

```
LNK1104 cannot open file 'glew32.lib'
```

For 64 bit configuration, I never define any glew32.lib kind of thing, but I get this error.

Any comments?

Best regards,

fercis

Comment: you said you set up `glew64.lib` name but it's giving you the `glew32.lib` error. If you compile for 64 bit the error should at least mention `glew64.lib` shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, that just make us confused...

Comment: Did you create the 64 bit target from the 32 bit configuration? Note that you have to edit the project twice then as "debug" and "release" targets have their own configuration each.

Comment: Could you control that you use the 64 bits configuration that you have configured? I once had a similar problem with a Debug/Release config difference...